# OMXplayer and HDMI audio on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: debian, video, raspberry-pi

When I try playing video using the command:

`omxplayer -o hdmi`

sound will not work unless I also include the `-r` switch.

The only problem with this is when the video is done it leaves a black screen up and I am unable to use the device until restart.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Easiest thing to do is not using the terminal over HDMI but instead log in from another computer using SSH …

Answer (score 1):

Have you uncommented `hdmi_drive=2` from `/boot/config.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on one of the TV's i'm using for a project (I have a few different models and i'm trying to create a generic image that works on all of them).

As part of the exit sequence if you run `tvservice -o && tvservice -p && fbset -depth 8 && fbset -depth 16` it should refresh the power state and wake up the display.

`tvservice -o` sends the signal to sleep the HDMI device.

`tvservice -p` brings it back on with preferred settings

`fbset -depth 8 && fbset -depth 16` forces a change that brings X back after the sleep.

This also resolved an issue i had with the display looking like garbage after playing a standard definition video (again; only on one of the displays i have been testing against)

In my situation i have an application monitoring for omxplayer to exit which then executes that sequence. You could simply wrap the call to omxplayer or edit the omxplayer script directly.

Note: i found this thread because i was trying to find a solution to audio not working on an experimental branch of omxplayer that supports constant looping and `-r` fixed me up. so thanks for that. =-)